# Using Comparator to order ArrayList Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

I have to order Appointments by date and time. I have an ArrayList of Appointments and have tried to create a comparator to compare their dates and times. I am trying to use the Collections.sort method, passing it the ArrayList of Appointments and the AppointmentComparator I have created. When compiling I get a "No suitable method for sort." Here's a link to the full error message generated by the compiler : http://prntscr.com/7y4qb

Comparator:

```
public class AppointmentComparator implements Comparator<Appointment>
{
public int compare(Appointment a, Appointment b)
{
    if (a.getDay() < b.getDay())
        return -1;

    if (a.getDay() == b.getDay())
    {
        if (a.getStart() < b.getStart())
            return -1;
        if (a.getStart() > b.getStart())
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Line with syntax error:

```
Collections.sort(book, new AppointmentComparator());
```

variable book is an ArrayList of Appointments. `ArrayList<Appointment>`

AppointmentBook class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class AppointmentBook
{
private ArrayList<Appointment> book;

public AppointmentBook()
{
    book = new ArrayList<Appointment>();
}

public void addAppointment(Appointment appt)
{
    book.add(appt);
    Collections.sort(book, new AppointmentComparator());
}

public String printAppointments(int day)
{
    String list = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < book.size(); i++)
    {
        if (book.get(i).getDay() == day)
        {
            list = list + "Appointment description: " + book.get(i).getDescription() + "\n" + "Date of Appointment: " +
            book.get(i).getDay() + "\n" + "Time: " + book.get(i).getStart() + " - " + book.get(i).getEnd() + "\n" + "\n";
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Appointment class:

```
public class Appointment
{
private String desc;
private int day; //in format mmddyyyy
private int start; //in format hhmm
private int end; //in format hhmm

public Appointment(String description, int aptDay, int startTime, int endTime)
{
    desc = description;
    day = aptDay;
    start = startTime;
    end = endTime;
}

public String getDescription()
{
    return desc;
}

public int getDay()
{
    return day;
}

public int getStart()
{
    return start;
}

public int getEnd()
{
    return end;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the entire AppointmentComparator class for us? There may be a problem in the class definition itself, and we can only speculate without a compiler error/the class definition itself.

Comment: Can you also post how you defined the book variable before calling Collections.sort()?

Comment: Ok updated to include the entire class

Comment: We still need to see the declaration of `book`.

Comment: Well, book is an instance variable created within a class. It will be filled with Appointment objects specified by the user.

Comment: I do believe the comparator is done correctly, I just get the error message when trying to use Collections.sort(). A screenshot to the error message is above.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the error but so far I can't.  I'm not trying to be a pain, I really want to help solve this . . . can you post the actual code where `book` is declared and instantiated?

Comment: Yes. I just did it's in the original post

Comment: If it helps, the purpose of the assignment is to allow the user to enter an Appointment and to keep the appointments in a sorted array list by date and time.

Comment: So strange . . . it all compiles for me.  This probably isn't the issue but, what JDK are you using?

Comment: Also, can you post the `Appointment` class itself?  Maybe delete the commented out part of `AppointmentBook` so no one gives you a hard time about length.

Comment: This is so strange. I've tried everything and the 3 classes compile.  I even downloaded this BlueJ IDE that you're using and tried to do it all there - still no compilation issues.  Let me ask you this . . . are there any other classes besides these 3?  The reason I ask is that the error message you posted doesn't quite say which class / line number.

Comment: Here are the other classes I have. I can remove BinarySearcher as that applied to another solution. Driver is simply used to test the classes with main method. http://prntscr.com/7y5zk Screenshot of all classes

Comment: It still all compiles, not sure what this is.  Can you try a command-line `javac` of each class, instead of BlueJ, and see if you get compilation errors that way?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: The BlueJ program has been acting odd today during the writing of this project. Constant freezes and compiles take minutes at times.

Comment: If I turn this in to my teacher, surely he will notice that there is no syntax error, I guess that's all that matter at this point

Comment: From the command line, do:  `javac Appointment.java`, then `javac AppointmentComparator.java`, then `javac AppointmentBook.java`.  And see if you get any compile errors.

Comment: javac is not recognized as an internal command. You know what, Im just going to turn in what I have. Thank you so much for all of your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No prob, I only wish we could have solved this.  My hunch is it's a problem with the version of BlueJ you are using.  Your code definitely compiles with `javac`, IntelliJ IDEA, and the version of BlueJ I just installed.  Best of luck - check in again if you need anything.

Comment: Yeah, I'll try reinstalling BlueJ and the JDK. Thanks again

Comment: Please take lengthy discussions to chat, and return when you feel you have a solution. It helps keep things neat and tidy around here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the error message it looks like you forgot to declare your comparator as implementing the interface:

```
public class AppointmentComparator implements Comparator<Appointment> {}
```

It needs to have the implements part, not just contain the method.

Comment: Sorry I didn't initially add that, but yes it was there and I still get the error

Comment: @user1323008 - recompile everything ? if not, post the full code

Comment: Ill post the full code to the AppointmentBook class, which is where I am having the error. I know for sure the Comparator is done correctly.

Comment: Ok original question is edited with the class that is giving the error message. Ignore the comments

Comment: Hmm, my next step would be to go through and make sure all existing .class files from old output are deleted before recompiling.  (A "clean and  build" usually, don't know how to do this in blueJ.)  You could also try the explicit invocation of the method as `Collections.<Appointment>sort(book, comparator);`  What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your new AppointmentComparator

```
Collections.sort(book, new (Comparator)AppointmentComparator());
```

Answer (score 1):

Also we can use inner class for some cases:

```
public int indexOfLargest(ArrayList<QuakeEntry> Data) {
    Comparator<QuakeEntry> cmtr = new Comparator<QuakeEntry>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(QuakeEntry t, QuakeEntry t1) {
            if (t.getMagnitude() < t1.getMagnitude())
                return -1;
            if (t.getMagnitude() == t1.getMagnitude()) 
                return 1;
            if (t1.getMagnitude() > t1.getMagnitude())
                return 0;
        return 1;
        }
    };

    QuakeEntry max = Collections.max(Data, cmtr);
    int maxIndex = Data.indexOf(max);
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    System.out.println("//---------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("ArrayList sorted by Magnitude using inner class with Comparator");
    System.out.println("//---------------------------------------------------");
    Collections.sort(Data, cmtr);
    for (QuakeEntry qe : Data) {
        System.out.println(qe);
    }


    return maxIndex;
}
```

code for all classes:
https://github.com/Evegen55/Java_DukeEdu_Coursera_2/blob/master/Earthquakes_Programming%20and%20Interfaces/src/earthquakes_programming_and_interfaces/QuakeEntry.java

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have not implemented The comparator interface for your AppointmentComparator